# Is it possible to use hardware RNG with ccminer or similar mining software

Tags: mining-hardware, miner-configuration, mining-software, cryptonote

So - I have one of the original LockBox devices - we no longer use. It's basically a micro atx motherboard and enclosure with processor and hdd and ram... simple stuff. There is a hardware RNG on it though. They used a dremmel tool to scratch out the chip on the RNG so I have little info on it. I may just boot into a thumb drive with linux variant to check device id and info from the card talking to the OS... anyhow - my question is if it's possible to modify existing ccminer or other similar mining software that is published to make use of the hardware RNG and offload some of the task to that device - or if it makes any sense to do so?
I am specifically interested in the cryptonight/cryptonote algos and am looking to play around with these older machines I have sitting around taking up space.
Does anyone have any specifics on the flows of data and scratchpad that shows and talks more about the actual algo and when RNG is generated? I am guessing it's slower than pure CPU or GPU taks (on a pcie slot on motherboard) but I am wondering if it might be used to fill a bucket of pure random numbers - as opposed to the theoretical rng that most mining software is making - and perhaps speed up some hashing as a result? Just curios if anyone is doing any of the mining steps with real hardware RNG's in any way other than using cpu or gpu cycles...?

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in doing that. RNG's aren't used in hash functions, otherwise they wouldn't be deterministic.